# Rearranging 3D numpy arrays in a specific manner

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm working with 3D matrices in numpy. I'm actually passing these matrices to C using ctypes to carry out some calculation and then getting back a result. Now the thing is, my result is correct (I did the math on paper to verify), but it's just not in a form I want it to be.

Here's an example. I have a 3D array of the form:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

I need to convert it to a form where the ith columns of all 2D sub-matrices form a new 2D sub-matrix, as so:

```
array([[[ 0, 9,  18],
        [ 3, 12, 21],
        [ 6, 15, 24]],

       [[ 1, 10, 19],
        [ 4, 13, 22],
        [ 7, 16, 25]],

       [[2, 11, 20],
        [5, 14, 23],
        [8, 17, 26]]])
```

I have tried using various combinations of `np.rot90`, `np.flipud`, `np.fliplr`, all to no avail. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `[6, 13, 24]` in the desired output doesn't look right. I'm guessing that's an error.

Comment: Sorry about that. Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output is your initial array with the order of the axes reversed. That's how NumPy generalizes transposes to arbitrary-dimensional arrays, so you can use the `T` attribute for this:

```
In [3]: x
Out[3]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

In [4]: x.T
Out[4]: 
array([[[ 0,  9, 18],
        [ 3, 12, 21],
        [ 6, 15, 24]],

       [[ 1, 10, 19],
        [ 4, 13, 22],
        [ 7, 16, 25]],

       [[ 2, 11, 20],
        [ 5, 14, 23],
        [ 8, 17, 26]]])
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for the example code I provided, but for my actual problem, this solution wasn't sufficient, although it was a great starting point from where I did find the right solution. I had to jump through a few hoops but I did get it working. Thanks!